# Visual studio linked files with TFS - automated build does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I have two Visual Studio solutions, one for WebApi and one for WP7 development, I am linking some dto files from WP7 solution to WebApi solution, this works great.

I just added the solutions to Team Foundation Service preview, and tried to get it to build. Since the linked files doesnt get added to source control, I cant build the project, because it cant find the linked files.

I tried adding the WP7 solution to the same directory in TFS, but no luck.

Edit- More information: 
I get: CSC: Source file '....\TennisTracker.Client.Ui\TennisTracker.Client.Core\Models\GameDto.cs' could not be found

Then I add the client solution under "Edit build definition - Process - 1. Required - Items to build. I get this: C:\a\src\TennisTracker.Client\TennisTracker.Client.Ui\TennisTracker.Client.Ui.csproj (140): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight for Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.WindowsPhone71.Overrides.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

In the error console, in visual studio, it gives me this error: Error: API restriction: The assembly 'file:///C:\Users\markka\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\ae65cc1a-850e-4112-8c34-96674d8c79f3\2052550994\nunit.core.interfaces.dll' has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain.

The workspace is set to the entire directory, containing both solutions

Comment: First problem was project with the dto's not being built. The second problem was Team Foundation Service does not support windows phone yet, so it cant be built. I ended up moving the dtos into the web project, i guess thats where they belong anyway, and it built perfectly fine and ran tests as its supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the build definition you can define the workspaces which you can point / setup paths to the other project.

Best thing to do is post up the build error output and I can then hopefully let you know the exact path you need to setup

Comment: I tried changing build definition, workspace is set to include both solutions. I tried changing so it builds the client solution (containing the files), but then i get a different error... (Added more information to question).

Comment: After a bit of searching, I found that your suggestion was the solution to the question, and that TFS does not support building WP, which gave me the second error.

Comment: You can get TFS to build WP projects. It all depends on your TFS setup. Essentially you need to install the SDK on the server (which needs tweaking to install on a server OS)

Comment: Im using tfspreview.com, so don't really have access to the server. Hopefully MS will add support for this soon..